# How to exit R in the middle of a command?

Tags: r

I am trying to run code in `R` and I have repeatedly run into the very frustrating issue that, unlike in Terminal when you can just press `control-C` on the keyboard, or Python when you can just enter `exit()`, in `R` it does not appear to be possible to exit a command you are currently typing to get back to the basic command line-type interface. That is, when I'm typing some code in `R`, I have a bunch of plus signs to the left of what I'm typing rather than `>` symbols, and, rather than execute what I have typed, I want to exit it and return to having `>` symbols and thus be able to type a whole new command while keeping the R window and workspace open, I find it impossible to do so. Instead I end up having to just close the entire R window, save the workspace, and reopen it which is way more steps than I'm sure are necessary. I already looked around online trying to find a way to exit `R` commands in the situation I described, and I found:

```
1. "stopifnot("something that is not true")", which worked the first time I tried it but not the second (why? no idea)
2. "stop("string")", which did nothing when I tried it
3. "quit()", which also did nothing
```

Comment: How about typing `esc` on the keyboard?

Comment: I don't know how to reply to a specific comment, and it is also very frustrating that StackOverflow does not have a "reply" option for comments. However, I would like to make clear that I want to reply to Darren Tsai's suggestion here by saying I'll try that next time I run into this issue, and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Jinkinson, you can use the @USERNAME  to get someone's attention (but if Darren is the only comment under your question they will be notified)

Comment: You can encounter this easily just typing `1 + ` on the console and type `enter`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks, I encountered it and confirmed that pressing esc on the keyboard works just fine, so this problem is now resolved.